# How could I access a count of items from a child widget in Durandal?

Tags: binding, knockout.js, widget, durandal

I am using Durandaljs and I am creating some reusable widgets.  Widgets are great!  However, I'm trying to create a way to have one widget get the count of items in a child widget.

For example, I have two widgets, an accordion widget that just allows sections of a page to be collapsible, and a second widget that displays items in a list.

I need the heading of the accordion widget to have a count of child list items from another widget.  Or it might show a count of words, basically, it needs to specify what it is counting from inside its content, and that can differ depending on what type of content it contains.

I think in short, I just need a way to communicate between a parent widget and a child widget without hard coding knowledge of one widget inside the other widget, the developer needs to declare explicitly what they want the count to be.

Things I've tried but don't work or don't like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.counter = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    alert('init');
    var value = valueAccessor();
    $(element).text(bindingContext.$parent.settings.items.length);
},
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    alert('update');
    var value = valueAccessor();
    $(element).text(bindingContext.$parent.settings.items.length);
}
};
```

The above doesn't work because when I got it to "work", it only worked initially, updates didn't get displayed because it wasn't watching an observable, and changing to

```
bindingContext.$parent.settings.items().length
```

threw an error because inside of the bindingContext it isn't an observable, even though I used settings.items().length in the child widget and that worked because it is a bound observable that gets updated.

I also could write jQuery to count the items, but that doesn't seem right, considering it would be specific to an HTML block and not data items in an observable.

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', '.contentWidget', function () {
    var $t = $(this);
    var count = $('.contentItem', $t).length;
    var $parent = $t.closest('[data-countable]');
    var $countEl = $parent.find($parent.attr('data-countable'));
    if ($countEl) {
        $countEl.text(count);
    }
});
```

Lastly, surely someone else is doing something similar and I just haven't found it yet, or I'm missing a simple way to do this because I've missed something in either the durandal docs or the knockout docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to access a widget from another, i think you are better of sharing view models between widgets. some thing like this

```
<div data-bind="accordion:{headerModel:childViewModel}"></div>
<div data-bind="listItems:{itemsModel:childViewModel}"></div>
```

Comment: that is what I ended up doing.  I think that makes more sense.  in my case one widget will contain the other, but the idea is the same.  thanks!